# Leaflet Map easy Button: how to set icon?

Tags: leaflet, icon

I added an "easy button" to a simple Leaflet Map i'm working on, intended to be an info tab. I'm getting a blank tab, and while I see that the icon on the tab is intended to be a "font awesome" icon, I put my own icon in the code after "L.EasyButton" (see at the bottom of the enclosed code) but no dice.

Here is the map: https://pdxcyclesafetymap.neocities.org/

To be honest I forked the code for this from gitHub and have been experimenting with tweaking it here and there to customize the map, so apologies if I'm sharing too much code here, but I've noted that my attempts to remove unnecessary seeming lines of code often delete the entire map...

Code (with my attempt to insert a custom icon at the bottom):

```
var map = L.map('map',{
    center:[45.5230 , -122.6676],
    zoom: 13,
    minZoom: 13
    });

//BASEMAP

L.tileLayer ('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=b60c02dc2f1c476983e78e9b863fc6d1',{
    attribution: 'Map data © <a href="https://thunderforest.com">Thunderforest</a>'}).addTo(map);



//FATALITIES


var skull = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/blackSkull.svg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    popupAnchor: [-10, -30],
    }); 

function fatalitiesLayer (feature, 
layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h1>Cyclist Fatality</h1><p> "+feature.properties.name+
    "</p>"+feature.properties.description+
    "</p>Date: "+feature.properties.date+ 
    "</p>Location: "+feature.properties.location+ 
    "</p>Cause: "+feature.properties.cause+ 
    "</p>");
    layer.setIcon(skull); 
    }


L.geoJson(fatalities,{
    onEachFeature: fatalitiesLayer
    }).addTo(map);

//INTERSECTIONS

var intersectionsLOGO = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/intersectionLOGO.svg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    popupAnchor: [-10, -30],
    opacity: .5,
    pane: 'Intersectionspane',
    });

function IntersectionsLayer(feature, 
layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("dangerous intersection: <p>"+feature.properties.name+"</p>");
    layer.setIcon(intersectionsLOGO);
    layer.bringToBack;
}

L.geoJson(Intersections,{
    onEachFeature: IntersectionsLayer
}).addTo(map);

//SEGMENTS
function SegmentsLayer(feature, 
layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("dangerous road segment, proceed with caution");
}

function styleLines(feature) {
    return {
                color: "red",
                weight: 9,
                opacity: .5,
                dashArray: '10,7',
                lineJoin: 'round',  //miter | round | bevel 
            };           
}

L.geoJSON(segments,{
    onEachFeature: SegmentsLayer,
    style: styleLines
}).addTo(map);

//CONTROL BOX
(function(){

// This is for grouping buttons into a bar
// takes an array of `L.easyButton`s and
// then the usual `.addTo(map)`
L.Control.EasyBar = L.Control.extend({

  options: {
    position:       'topleft',  // part of leaflet's defaults
    id:             null,       // an id to tag the Bar with
    leafletClasses: true        // use leaflet classes?
  },


  initialize: function(buttons, options){

    if(options){
      L.Util.setOptions( this, options );
    }

    this._buildContainer();
    this._buttons = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
      buttons[i]._bar = this;
      buttons[i]._container = buttons[i].button;
      this._buttons.push(buttons[i]);
      this.container.appendChild(buttons[i].button);
    }

  },


  _buildContainer: function(){
    this._container = this.container = L.DomUtil.create('div', '');
    this.options.leafletClasses && L.DomUtil.addClass(this.container, 'leaflet-bar easy-button-container leaflet-control');
    this.options.id && (this.container.id = this.options.id);
  },


  enable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.container, 'enabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.container, 'disabled');
    this.container.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
    return this;
  },


  disable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.container, 'disabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.container, 'enabled');
    this.container.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    return this;
  },


  onAdd: function () {
    return this.container;
  },

  addTo: function (map) {
    this._map = map;

    for(var i = 0; i < this._buttons.length; i++){
      this._buttons[i]._map = map;
    }

    var container = this._container = this.onAdd(map),
        pos = this.getPosition(),
        corner = map._controlCorners[pos];

    L.DomUtil.addClass(container, 'leaflet-control');

    if (pos.indexOf('bottom') !== -1) {
      corner.insertBefore(container, corner.firstChild);
    } else {
      corner.appendChild(container);
    }

    return this;
  }

});

L.easyBar = function(){
  var args = [L.Control.EasyBar];
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    args.push( arguments[i] );
  }
  return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(L.Control.EasyBar, args));
};

// L.EasyButton is the actual buttons
// can be called without being grouped into a bar
L.Control.EasyButton = L.Control.extend({

  options: {
    position:  'topleft',       // part of leaflet's defaults

    id:        null,            // an id to tag the button with

    type:      'replace',       // [(replace|animate)]
                                // replace swaps out elements
                                // animate changes classes with all elements inserted

    states:    [],              // state names look like this
                                // {
                                //   stateName: 'untracked',
                                //   onClick: function(){ handle_nav_manually(); };
                                //   title: 'click to make inactive',
                                //   icon: 'fa-circle',    // wrapped with <a>
                                // }

    leafletClasses:   true,     // use leaflet styles for the button
    tagName:          'button',
  },



  initialize: function(icon, onClick, title, id){

    // clear the states manually
    this.options.states = [];

    // add id to options
    if(id != null){
      this.options.id = id;
    }

    // storage between state functions
    this.storage = {};

    // is the last item an object?
    if( typeof arguments[arguments.length-1] === 'object' ){

      // if so, it should be the options
      L.Util.setOptions( this, arguments[arguments.length-1] );
    }

    // if there aren't any states in options
    // use the early params
    if( this.options.states.length === 0 &&
        typeof icon  === 'string' &&
        typeof onClick === 'function'){

      // turn the options object into a state
      this.options.states.push({
        icon: icon,
        onClick: onClick,
        title: typeof title === 'string' ? title : ''
      });
    }

    // curate and move user's states into
    // the _states for internal use
    this._states = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.states.length; i++){
      this._states.push( new State(this.options.states[i], this) );
    }

    this._buildButton();

    this._activateState(this._states[0]);

  },

  _buildButton: function(){

    this.button = L.DomUtil.create(this.options.tagName, '');

    if (this.options.tagName === 'button') {
        this.button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    }

    if (this.options.id ){
      this.button.id = this.options.id;
    }

    if (this.options.leafletClasses){
      L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, 'easy-button-button leaflet-bar-part leaflet-interactive');
    }

    // don't let double clicks and mousedown get to the map
    L.DomEvent.addListener(this.button, 'dblclick', L.DomEvent.stop);
    L.DomEvent.addListener(this.button, 'mousedown', L.DomEvent.stop);

    // take care of normal clicks
    L.DomEvent.addListener(this.button,'click', function(e){
      L.DomEvent.stop(e);
      this._currentState.onClick(this, this._map ? this._map : null );
      this._map && this._map.getContainer().focus();
    }, this);

    // prep the contents of the control
    if(this.options.type == 'replace'){
      this.button.appendChild(this._currentState.icon);
    } else {
      for(var i=0;i<this._states.length;i++){
        this.button.appendChild(this._states[i].icon);
      }
    }
  },


  _currentState: {
    // placeholder content
    stateName: 'unnamed',
    icon: (function(){ return document.createElement('span'); })()
  },



  _states: null, // populated on init



  state: function(newState){

    // activate by name
    if(typeof newState == 'string'){

      this._activateStateNamed(newState);

    // activate by index
    } else if (typeof newState == 'number'){

      this._activateState(this._states[newState]);
    }

    return this;
  },


  _activateStateNamed: function(stateName){
    for(var i = 0; i < this._states.length; i++){
      if( this._states[i].stateName == stateName ){
        this._activateState( this._states[i] );
      }
    }
  },

  _activateState: function(newState){

    if( newState === this._currentState ){

      // don't touch the dom if it'll just be the same after
      return;

    } else {

      // swap out elements... if you're into that kind of thing
      if( this.options.type == 'replace' ){
        this.button.appendChild(newState.icon);
        this.button.removeChild(this._currentState.icon);
      }

      if( newState.title ){
        this.button.title = newState.title;
      } else {
        this.button.removeAttribute('title');
      }

      // update classes for animations
      for(var i=0;i<this._states.length;i++){
        L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._states[i].icon, this._currentState.stateName + '-active');
        L.DomUtil.addClass(this._states[i].icon, newState.stateName + '-active');
      }

      // update classes for animations
      L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.button, this._currentState.stateName + '-active');
      L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, newState.stateName + '-active');

      // update the record
      this._currentState = newState;

    }
  },

  enable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, 'enabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.button, 'disabled');
    this.button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
    return this;
  },

  disable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, 'disabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.button, 'enabled');
    this.button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    return this;
  },

  onAdd: function(map){
    var bar = L.easyBar([this], {
      position: this.options.position,
      leafletClasses: this.options.leafletClasses
    });
    this._anonymousBar = bar;
    this._container = bar.container;
    return this._anonymousBar.container;
  },

  removeFrom: function (map) {
    if (this._map === map)
      this.remove();
    return this;
  },

});

L.easyButton = function(/* args will pass automatically */){
  var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply([L.Control.EasyButton],arguments);
  return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(L.Control.EasyButton, args));
};

/*************************
 *
 * util functions
 *
 *************************/

// constructor for states so only curated
// states end up getting called
function State(template, easyButton){

  this.title = template.title;
  this.stateName = template.stateName ? template.stateName : 'unnamed-state';

  // build the wrapper
  this.icon = L.DomUtil.create('span', '');

  L.DomUtil.addClass(this.icon, 'button-state state-' + this.stateName.replace(/(^\s*|\s*$)/g,''));
  this.icon.innerHTML = buildIcon(template.icon);
  this.onClick = L.Util.bind(template.onClick?template.onClick:function(){}, easyButton);
}

function buildIcon(ambiguousIconString) {

  var tmpIcon;

  // does this look like html? (i.e. not a class)
  if( ambiguousIconString.match(/[&;=<>"']/) ){

    // if so, the user should have put in html
    // so move forward as such
    tmpIcon = ambiguousIconString;

  // then it wasn't html, so
  // it's a class list, figure out what kind
  } else {
      ambiguousIconString = ambiguousIconString.replace(/(^\s*|\s*$)/g,'');
      tmpIcon = L.DomUtil.create('span', '');

      if( ambiguousIconString.indexOf('fa-') === 0 ){
        L.DomUtil.addClass(tmpIcon, 'fa '  + ambiguousIconString)
      } else if ( ambiguousIconString.indexOf('glyphicon-') === 0 ) {
        L.DomUtil.addClass(tmpIcon, 'glyphicon ' + ambiguousIconString)
      } else {
        L.DomUtil.addClass(tmpIcon, /*rollwithit*/ ambiguousIconString)
      }

      // make this a string so that it's easy to set innerHTML below
      tmpIcon = tmpIcon.outerHTML;
  }

  return tmpIcon;
}

})();

var helloPopup = L.popup().setContent("<img src='images/cog.png'style=width:150px;height:150px;</img><br><b>Portland Cycle Safety Map</b><br />This map is intended to bring dangerous intersections <br />and street segments to the attention of Portland area cyclists: this is a work in progress.<br />Each skull marks the location a cyclist has been killed by an automobile sometime between 2005 and 2017.<br /"
);

L.easyButton('images/blackSkull.svg', function(btn, map){
    helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to `L.easyButton` you use is `'images/blackSkull.svg'`, which ends up on the button as a CSS class name: `<span class="images/blackSkull.svg"></span>`.

You can use a complete HTML tag instead:

```
L.easyButton('<img src="https://pdxcyclesafetymap.neocities.org/images/blackSkull.svg" style="width:16px">', function(btn, map){
    helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
}).addTo(map);
```

I set a `width` here because your image is a SVG. Without any size restrictions (width, height) only the top left part of the image would be visible (just white space).

Comment: Thanks. How can one style the icon once it's within the button? I'd like to center it, etc.

Comment: @EdwardCurran you can give it a CSS class `class="myicon"` and then use CSS `margin` and `padding` on the image (or surrounding element), I'm not exactly sure, you'll have to try

Comment: How would one do this with a local file?

Comment: @jzadra You should be able to just use a relative path in the HTML image, like `<img src="some_image.png">`, if that is what you mean by "local file"